# python pandas datatype error float is required

Tags: python, types, pandas

I am trying to read data from a csv file and calculate bearing from coordinates.But I get error 'a float is required'. The function itself works if I run the function by itself (not using loop) with only two coordinates. So I think the issue is related to the last 'for' statement. I wonder if anybody has an idea where and how I should set float datatype? Thank you.

```
from math import *
import pandas as p
import numpy as np

bearingdata = 'xxxxxx.csv'
data = p.read_csv(bearingdata)

lat = [float(i) for i in data.Lat]
lon = [float(j) for j in data.Lon]

lat1 = lat[0: (len(lat) -2)]
lon1 = lon[0: (len(lon) -2)]
lat2 = lat[1: (len(lat) -1)]
lon2 = lon[1: (len(lon) -1)]

def bearing(lon_1, lat_1, lon_2, lat_2):

    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
        lon_1, lat_1, lon_2, lat_2 = map(radians, [lon_1, lat_1, lon_2, lat_2])

    #now calcuate bearing   

    Bearing = atan2(cos(lat1)*sin(lat2)-sin(lat1)*cos(lat2)*cos(lon2-lon1),sin(lon2-lon1)*cos(lat2))
    Bearing = degrees(Bearing)
    Bearing = (Bearing + 360) % 360

    return Bearing   

count = 0
for x in lat1:
    print str(count) + "\n"

    angle = bearing(lon1[count], lat1[count], lon2[count], lat2[count])
    print "the bearing between " + str(lat1[count]) + "," + str(lon1[count]) + " and " + str(lat2[count]) + "," + str(lon2[count]) + " is: " + str(angle) + "degrees \n"   
    count = count + 1
```

*** trace back ***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):<br>
File "bearing.py", line 34, in <module><br>
angle = bearing(lon1[count], lat1[count], lon2[count], lat2[count])<br>
File "bearing.py", line 23, in bearing<br>
Bearing = atan2(cos(lat1)*sin(lat2)-sin(lat1)*cos(lat2)*cos(lon2-lon1),sin(lon2-lon1)*cos(lat2))<br>
TypeError: a float is required
```

*** original data looks like this ***

Lat (column name)
42.xxxxxx
... many rows

Lon (column name)
78.xxxx
... many rows

Comment: Can you provide the traceback?

Comment: don't use the `math` library with `numpy` objects

Comment: It doesn't matter that you're reading the data from a CSV. Completely irrelevant. It would be infinitely more useful to know what the first 10 or so rows of the data look like. Please edit your question to include them.

Comment: Hello AtAFork, I added trackback. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Paul, they are decimal number lat/lon (eg.42.xxxxxx, 78.xxxxxx). The numbers change every row (10 - 30 rows in each file I have). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost never need to loop in pandas. Try something like this:

#### Generate some fake coordinates

```
import pandas
import numpy as np

N = 10
np.random.seed(0)
degree_data = pandas.DataFrame({
    'lat': np.random.uniform(low=-90, high=90, size=N),
    'lon': np.random.uniform(low=-180, high=180, size=N),
})
```

#### `degree_data` looks like this:

```
         lat         lon
0   8.786431  105.021014
1  38.734086   10.402171
2  18.497408   24.496042
3   8.078973  153.214790
4 -13.742136 -154.427019
5  26.260940 -148.633452
6 -11.234302 -172.721377
7  70.519140  119.743144
8  83.459297  100.136430
9 -20.980527  133.204373
```

#### convert to radians and shift everything up 1 row so that we can look ahead

```
radian_data = np.round(np.radians(degree_data), 2)
radian_data = radian_data.join(radian_data.shift(-1), lsuffix='1', rsuffix='2')
print(radian_data)
```

so now `radian_data` is:

```
   lat1  lon1  lat2  lon2
0  0.15  1.83  0.68  0.18
1  0.68  0.18  0.32  0.43
2  0.32  0.43  0.14  2.67
3  0.14  2.67 -0.24 -2.70
4 -0.24 -2.70  0.46 -2.59
5  0.46 -2.59 -0.20 -3.01
6 -0.20 -3.01  1.23  2.09
7  1.23  2.09  1.46  1.75
8  1.46  1.75 -0.37  2.32
9 -0.37  2.32   NaN   NaN
```

#### Define a bearing function that takes row from our dataframe

```
def bearing(row):
    x = np.cos(row.lat1)*np.sin(row.lat2) - \
        np.sin(row.lat1)*np.cos(row.lat2)*np.cos(row.lon2-row.lon1)
    y = np.sin(row.lon2-row.lon1)*np.cos(row.lat2)
    Bearing = np.degrees(np.arctan2(x, y))
    return (Bearing + 360) % 360
```

#### `apply` that function to each row, save in the original dataframe

```
degree_data['bearing'] = radian_data.apply(bearing, axis=1)
# so now we have 
         lat         lon     bearing
0   8.786431  105.021014  140.855914
1  38.734086   10.402171  305.134809
2  18.497408   24.496042   22.751374
3   8.078973  153.214790  337.513363
4 -13.742136 -154.427019   81.301311
5  26.260940 -148.633452  235.214299
6 -11.234302 -172.721377  108.063240
7  70.519140  119.743144   98.957144
8  83.459297  100.136430  301.528278
9 -20.980527  133.204373         NaN
```

Comment: Hi Paul, in my data file, there is one column for Lat and one column for Lon. In the first iteration, lat/lon in row 1 are lat1/lon1 and lat/lon in row 2 are lat2/lon2. Then in the next iteration, the lat/lon in the row 2 becomes lat1/lon1, lat/lon in row 2 become lat2/lon2. It moves down the columns successively ... So I wonder how I can modify your code?

Comment: I did find the module name are different in numpy and math (atan2 and arctan2) so maybe something is getting consufed ...

Comment: @Sumi -- 1) edit your question to include some data (literally copy and paste the first ten rows into the question). 2) the `math` module assumes that you're using native python types, and numpy has its own types for ints and floats. if you have numpy, there's rarely a reason to use `math`. show me your data and we'll be able to get my solution to work.

Comment: @sumi, I added what my mocked up data looks like. I this this matches the description of your data

Comment: Paul, thanks. Your code perfectly works. I am just trying to figure out how I can import data from my csv file as dataframe. Getting close ...

Answer (score 0):

Add a decimal to your math in the function:

```
Bearing = (Bearing + 360) % 360.0
```

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer